# How to add two or more column in third column in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

For Example 
Roll No,   Name,          Maths,   English,     Total(Maths+English)

Comment: You might want to update your question with more information. Welcome to SO, but this is vague..

Comment: Is this adding it to a *query* (i.e. a `SELECT` statement) or adding it to the *table*? The answers are quite different

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [computed column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Assuming columns `Maths` and `English` are a numeric type, you can do like so:

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD Total AS Maths + English;
```

Once created, you access the column (read only, obviously) as you would any other column, i.e.

```
select English, Maths, Total from [MyTable];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Roll No, Name, Maths, English, Maths+English AS TOTAL
FROM  [YOUR TABLE]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the Total column a function
go to the table in design view mode, then click on Total column (I assume
you already have this column, if not create it first, and then click on it in design view)

then from column properties expand 'Computer Column Specification'
then in forumula field write:
(Maths+English)